# What's best way to present no-cache?

Tags: html, no-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

I am just curious as one html tag it's efficient for no-cache.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

or

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Comment: You can use both together. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: Does this effect anything at all? Page load, recursive cache'ing? What are the pros and cons of using both?

Comment: Different browsers may support different http-equivs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User agents are not required to support meta data mechanisms:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.1

Using one or both shouldn't cause problems, but it would probably be more effective to send a NO-CACHE directive over HTTP.